# JPA Metamodel doesn't generate sources after moving to spring boot 3 and java 17

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-17, hibernate-6.x

After moving the spring boot project from 2.0 to 3.0 and upgrading to java 17, hibernate-jpamodelgen doesn't generate a metamodel classes.

I added this dependency, but it still doesn't work. Could someone help?

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be caused by hibernate-jpamodelgen itself. Check your build to make sure that the other annotation processors in your build are working correctly and there are no other compiler errors. For me, the metamodel classes were only generated after all of the other errors were resolved.

When I encountered this behavior after upgrading, I had `@ContructorBinding` annotations where they were no longer supported. Removing these bad annotations fixed the problem.

This source helped me figure out what was going on: [A less expected way JPA metamodel generation can fail](https://engineering.leanix.net/blog/jpa-metamodel-generation-failing/.)

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I had the same problem.

Comment: I had annotation in my code @org.hibernate.annotations.Type which caused this. I missed this errorr among other compilation errors related to absent metamodel class.

Answer (score 0):

During the migration to Java 19 with Spring Boot 3.2.1, which utilizes Hibernate 6, I encountered an issue related to annotation processing. To resolve this, the following steps were taken:

**Updated Dependency:** The hibernate-jpamodelgen dependency was updated to the newer version. The updated dependency in the pom.xml file is as follows:

> org.hibernate
>     hibernate-jpamodelgen
>     6.4.1.Final
>     provided

**Modified Maven Compiler Plugin Configuration:** The Maven Compiler Plugin was reconfigured to support Java 19, ensuring proper functioning of annotation processors. The revised plugin configuration is:

> org.apache.maven.plugins
> maven-compiler-plugin
>
> 19
> 19
>
>
> org.hibernate
> hibernate-jpamodelgen
> 6.4.1.Final

These changes ensured that other annotation processors in the build worked correctly and rectified the encountered issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).